# GIT: How to keep ignored files when switching branches?

Tags: git, git-branch, gitignore

I have an App.Local.config file which each developer has their own settings in.  I do not want this file checked versioned in the GIT repo as every time it would be overwritten by another developers changes.

So I deleted the file from the repo and added it to the ignore file.  But now when developers switch branches, App.Local.config is deleted from their local filesystem.

Ultimately what i would like is:

1. new dev clones repo, gets a starting version of App.Local.config
2. dev makes changes to App.Local.config.  Git will ignore changes and not stage/checkin
3. dev switches branches, changes to App.Local.config will not be lost and file is not deleted.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: If the file is correctly ignored, it should not be touched when switching branches. Does it appear when you type `git status`?

Comment: It will only be deleted on the first update for everyone. Once everyone's repos are up to date, the file will remain and not be deleted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What probably happened is that you removed the file from your workspace but not from the index. If you did that git thinks that removing this file is a change and it will remove it from then on.

The way to go is to remove the file you don't want to track anymore from the index with

```
git rm --cached App.Local.config
```

and then add that file to the `.gitignore`
Doing that you will have no more problems with the file

Comment: @mswanson If the file is ignored, you can switch branches as you wish - it would not be touched. So you have only one problem: provide devs with template for this file. But you should do it off the git.

Comment: if the file is ignored and out of the index the changes to the file are not lost and the file is not deleted

Comment: @iberbeu I have the same problem but the file has never been in the index. I started a new branch with the --orphan flag, then git rm --cached everything, ignored some files in .gitignore and committed. Those files disappear when I switch branches and I don't know how to avoid that!

Comment: If the files disappear after changing the branch is because they are in the index. I suggest you `git rm --cached` them and then add them to the `.gitignore`. I guess when you committed, those files where committed as well. If the case is different just open another question so that we can discuss it there

Comment: @splinter123 See the Eki's answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552959/git-how-to-keep-ignored-files-when-switching-branches/48237321#48237321], in short you should remove that file from all branch and all its .gitignore then it will not disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `git rm --cached App.Local.config` not only in you working branch but also in the branch you want to switch to, or you will lose your `App.Local.config` when you switch back to the branch you worked if you only use `git rm --cached App.Local.config` in that branch.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this file was in index once. So its deletion **is** a change. You can add it to `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude` and then just recreate it on each developers machine.