# Keep ignored files when switching branches in git

Tags: git, gitignore, git-index

Eclipse has it's own files `.project`, `.classpath` and `.settings` folder. In git, I have them in the `.gitignore` file, because I don't want them to be tracked in the remote repository. My problem is that when I switch branch, and then switch back, those files have been removed, so eclipse doesn't recognize the project and I have to import it again so they're generated.

Is there a way to tell git to ignore those files, but keep them in the local repo or something so I don't loose them when switching branches, but changes to them are not tracked and they're not pushed to the remote either?

Files are shown when running `git ls-files -o`.

I've checked [GIT: How to keep ignored files when switching branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552959/git-how-to-keep-ignored-files-when-switching-branches), but the file still appears when doing `git status`.

EDIT:

`git status` alone shows this:

```
$ git status
On branch refactorizacion
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/refactorizacion'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

This doesn't work:

```
$ git add -f .project
$ git rm --cached .project
```

I've also tried this, but file appears after `git status`:

```
$ git add -f .project
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged .project
$ git status
On branch refactorizacion
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/refactorizacion'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   .project
```

Comment: Can you show the output of your git status?

Comment: @TheGeorgeous I edited the question with more information

Comment: @carcaret did you find a solution to the problem? I have the same and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The second one will obviously not work. You are adding a file to index, but without committing, it does not know which previous version to compare with. So git status will show it as a new file. You can only apply update-index after you have committed it once.

In the first case, I am not sure why you would add a file before removing it.

As mentioned in the question you have referred to, you should simply remove the file (if git is still tracking it) and add it to `.gitignore`, so that git does not track it anymore. This will insulate it from branch switching.

EDIT:
Make sure that the file was removed using `git rm <file>` and that the commit in which this was added is present in all branches. Then add the file to gitignore.

Comment: The file is **not** being tracked by git, it's **not** in the remote, and **it is in** `.gitignore`. If I `git clone` the repository, the file `.project` doesn't exist, then I import it in eclipse and the file is created, but when switching branches, it dissapears again. Is possible for it not to be deleted, but also not to be tracked by git?

Comment: When the file is created and you run git status, what is the output??

Comment: It's the first bit of code I wrote, everything up to date and nothing to commit.

Comment: And you have never added .project to your git repo ever before

Comment: I have. In the beginning it was added, then I removed it from the repo since I didn't want it in the remote. What I can't recall is the way I removed it.

Comment: But, what if the file wasn't removed that way? I'm not sure if I just did `rm .project` and then add it to `.gitignore` and commit both changes, or I also recall trying with `git clean` something, honestly can't remember. Isn't there a way to fix it now?