# Git: keep ignored files when switching branches

Tags: git

I know it seems like a duplicate of [GIT: How to keep ignored files when switching branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552959/git-how-to-keep-ignored-files-when-switching-branches), but I couldn't find my answer there.

So I created a new branch with the `--orphan` flag, to delete the commit history. Then I did `git rm --cached` on all the files, modified `.gitignore` to ignore some of them, then added and committed. As expected, the ignored files are not in the new repo (nor in any of its history). However, they disappear when I switch branches (that is, when I check out an old branch, then check out the new one again). How can I avoid that?

EDIT: The purpose of the whole operation was to prepare a project to be published on GitHub, so I wanted to hide some config files that contain private information like passwords, keys, etc. That's why I deleted the commit history by creating a new orphan branch. I understand that probably committing the files before adding them to `.gitignore` would solve the disappearing issue, but that would make the files ultimately visible in the public history. I tried to do `git add -f`, then `git rm --cached`, but it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: What is the nature of these ignored files?  Are they local config files or something else?  Are these files versioned in the other branches?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added more details in the question. Yes the files are versioned in the other branches, I just put them in the gitignore file of the new branch that is meant to go public.

Answer (score 7):

> However, they disappear when I switch branches (that is, when I check out an old branch, then check out the new one again). How can I avoid that?

You cannot.  This is by-design.  In your `publish` branch, you do not have the files tracked, and you have a `.gitignore` for them.  Great!  But when you switch to some other branch that *does* have those files tracked, they will be checked out to your working directory.  This is because a `.gitignore` only applies to untracked files.

From [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html):

> A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected.

Now if you try to switch back to your `publish` branch, the files will be removed on-disk because they do not exist in that branch.  Your `.gitignore` for these files is ignored because they are tracked and it would not apply to them.

(Note that they are - by definition - tracked *even if they're in the branch that you're switching away from*.  This is mostly just an implementation detail and I concede that this may not be intuitive.)

What you want to do is remove every occurrence of these files *in all the branches*.  Use a tool like [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to remove these files from your history *completely*, in all branches.  Then you can safely `.gitignore` them, then once they're gone *completely* you can safely push this to GitHub.

Comment: It was me, and the downvote was too harsh for the mistake in this answer.

Comment: @jthill What mistake is that?

Comment: It's that "because they are tracked" doesn't explain anything -- in the new branch, they _aren't_ tracked.  It's the transition from present-in-the-old-checkout to not-present-in-the-new-checkout that causes git to update the worktree.

Comment: They're in the index at the time of the invocation of the checkout command.  Thus, they're tracked.

Comment: See?  That's correct, and your answer makes perfect sense to someone who understands what "tracked" means ... but, someone who understands that wouldn't be asking OP's question.

Comment: That's a reasonable criticism.  :)

Comment: @jthill I know what "tracked" means, like anyone who's used git. Asking a question here doesn' mean you're a total illitterate.