# How to keep in the work-tree tracked files in branch A but ignored in branch B when switching from A to B?

Tags: git

I have a git-based deploy setup where the production machine has a clone of a "deploy" branch, I use that deploy branch to track configuration files that should not be tracked by development branches, like credentials files.
I need to use some of the untracked configuration files in the development branch locally, but git won't keep that files in the work-tree when switching from deploy branch. To be able to use that files, I need to do

```
git checkout deploy configuration/file
git reset HEAD configuration/file
```

How can I make git keep the untracked files in the work-tree?

To reproduce this problem, you can do

```
git init test-repo
cd test-repo
git checkout -b A
echo 'null' > A_file
git add A_file
git commit -m "Make branch A"
git checkout -b B
echo 'null' > B_file
git add B_file
git commit -m "Make branch B"
```

Right now you are in branch `B`, switch to branch A (`git checkout A`) and you will see that `B_file` is not in the work-tree.

Comment: I would think git is not suited for that. Or maybe you'd need to use [git clean](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) after a checkout.

Comment: @evolutionxbox the `git reset` removes the file from development branch's index. May I need to write a script to be ran after each branch switching?

Comment: I think reset removes it from the index. From what I read you don't need that. You want to remove a file that sticks when switching branches. I'm thinking reset won't do that.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Well sorry if I was not clear enough. but the question starts with "How to *keep in the work-tree* tracked files...". I want to keep in the work-tree but not in the index, the file is tracked by the deploy branch only, but I need to use it while working in the development branch.

Comment: If a file is in branch A, but not B. Switching to B won't remove it unless A contains a commit removing that branch.

Comment: @evolutionxbox removing from work-tree is different of removing from repository, git is removing from work-tree when switching from A to B. Work tree is the files you actually see in the repository's working directory.

Comment: "git is removing from work-tree when switching from A to B" - so B _must_ contain a commit which removes that file. You could checkout the file from that branch after switching? `git checkout B; git checkout A myfile.txt`

Comment: @evolutionxbox I added steps to reproduce the problem in the question, try that. In the example there is no commit removing `B_file` from branch `A` since it has never tracked by that branch.

Comment: This may be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37207628/git-keep-ignored-files-when-switching-branches

Comment: Thank you for adding those steps. --- git is removing a file which was added in one commit and is not present in another. To prevent this the file should not be committed at all. My earlier comment was misleading, apologies.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I am tracking the file in deploy because I use `git push production deploy` to deploy the program into the production machine. But that's true, if I remove the file from deploy branch, the file will be in the work-tree even if I switch branches.

Comment: `git checkout A; echo 'null' > C_file; git checkout B` the C_file will still be there, but as it's not tracked, it cannot be pushed. This is why continuous integration systems keep configs outside of git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: *Don't even try to do that.*  You can't make Git do what you want here.  The reason *why* that's the answer is a bit long and includes some technical definitions.

First, we should note that Git isn't really about *branches* (or at least branch *names*).  Git is really all about *commits*.  Commits are what get shared from one Git repository to another.  The `git push` operation sends commits from your Git to the other Git.  Branch names merely serve to help us (and Git) *locate* the commits; the `git push` operation that sends some commit(s) ends with a request to have the *other* Git *remember* that commit, typically via a branch name in that other Git.<sup>1</sup>  So let's take a brief—okay, brief for me —look at commits before we dive into Git's index and your work-tree.

---

<sup>1</sup>This means, among other things, that you don't actually need to use a branch name in *your* Git, but you will need to use a name in the *other* Git.  There's no reason to do this, and it's usually a bad idea to do work on a detached HEAD, but it's technically *possible*.

---

#### Commits

Remember these things about commits:

- Each one is numbered with a big ugly hash ID.
- The numbers look random, but aren't.  Each is actually a cryptographic checksum of the complete content of the internal commit object.  All Gits compute these the same way, which is how we get the two Gits to agree that *this* commit gets its particular number.
- Each commit contains two parts.  First there's the main data, which is a snapshot of all of the files Git knows about at the time you make the commit.  We'll concentrate on that part in a moment.  Then there's the metadata, containing things such as the name and email address of the author of the commit.  The metadata also contain the hash ID of the previous or *parent* commit, or for merge commits, two or more previous commits.
- Because of the hash IDs, the contents of any commit are frozen for all time: nobody can change any of this.
- To keep the space usage of all these snapshots low, and because the files in the commits are frozen, Git de-duplicates the files.

So this means that a commit that mostly re-uses files from other commits takes almost no space: just a bit for the author and committer data, plus maybe a few objects unique to this particular commit.  But it also means that the files *in* each commit are useless for getting any new work done.

#### Commit content, Git's index, and your work-tree

Version control systems in general all tend to share this "frozen commit, usable work" pattern, and here Git is not yet different: when you check out (or switch to) a commit—which Git does by its hash ID, typically using a branch name to *find* the hash ID—Git copies the frozen-format files, which aren't readable by non-Git programs and which cannot be changed, to ordinary everyday read/write files.  So you get two copies of each "active", or current-commit, file.  The useful one is in what Git calls your working tree or work-tree.

Here, though, Git departs from most VCSes: instead of having just these necessary *two* copies of each file, Git adds a *third copy*.  This third copy is in the frozen *format*, and is already de-duplicated, so that it's usually not a copy after all anyway.  This third "copy" is in what Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.

The index has multiple roles, but the main one we care about here is how it's used to make *new commits*.  This is its staging area role.  When you `git checkout` some commit, Git fills its index from the commit you select.  So now the index holds every file that was *in* that commit—and *only* those files.  These are, in effect, the files that Git knows about.

Git also copies these files to your work-tree, expanding them out into useful form.  That means on an initial checkout from a newly cloned repository, for instance, you now have three copies of each file from whatever commit is the last one on whatever branch you've chosen.  All three of them match, and two of them—the committed copy and the index copy—are actually sharing the underlying storage (possibly with many other commits as well).

#### Switching commits

Since the index stores each file in the de-duplicated (numbered by internal hash ID) form, as does each commit, Git immediately knows, when you switch from one commit to another, which files in the two commits are *the same* and which ones are different, and which entries in the index might need updating.  This enables Git to remove and/or replace only those files that need to be removed-and-replaced.  So switching from commit `a123456` to commit `fedcba9` can be very quick, and hardly disturbs your work-tree at all, if those commits are similar.

#### Building a new commit

When you run `git commit`, Git will build a new commit.  This new commit needs a snapshot.  The snapshot is provided by whatever is in Git's index *right then*.

These files—the ones in Git's index—are, in essence, the proposed next commit.  They are the files that Git knows about.  They are already in the frozen and de-duplicated format, ready to go into a new commit: there is hardly any actual *work* to do to make that new commit.  Git just needs to turn the index into an internal Git *tree object* and wrap that tree object with a commit with the right metadata.

The parent of the new commit will be the current commit.  You will be the author and committer—Git needs your name and email address at this point.  The date-and-time-stamps in the metadata will be "now", and the act of writing out this data will provide the new random-looking hash ID for your new commit.

Having produced this commit, Git now writes its hash ID into the current *branch name*, so that your branch name now identifies the new final commit on this branch.  If multiple branch names identified the commit that *was* last, that you checked out earlier to get to this point, well, now the *name* you used in your `git checkout` identifies this new commit instead.  The other names still identify the old commit, that is now the parent of this new one.

#### Tracked files, untracked files, and `.gitignore`

This also gets us to the definition of a *tracked file* vs an *untracked file*.  Given that your work-tree is *yours*, you can do anything you like with it, including creating files that Git doesn't know about.  These files are not in Git's index, and that makes them untracked.

That's it: an untracked file is simply any file that *is* in your work-tree right now, and is *not* in Git's index right now.  Given that you can create and remove work-tree files at will, you can make new untracked files any time, and remove them any time.

Given `git add` and `git rm --cached`, you can also put a file into Git's index at any time, or remove one from Git's index at any time.  Note that `git add` means *make the index copy of this named file match the work-tree copy:* if you remove the work-tree copy of file *F* and then run `git add F`, Git will remove the index copy of *F* too.  But `git rm --cached` lets you remove the index copy without touching the work-tree copy.

The `.gitignore` file is not really about *ignoring* files.  If you run `git commit`, Git will make a new commit that contains exactly those files that are in Git's index.  If you haven't put a work-tree file into Git's index, or the work-tree copy and the index copy don't match, Git just uses whatever is in the index.  So there's no need to explicitly ignore anything: it's just a question of what's in the index.  If the file *is* there in the index, it *will be committed*, even if it's listed in `.gitignore`.

What `.gitignore` really does, then, is tell Git:

1. Don't *complain* that some file is in the work-tree, yet not in the index.  Normally `git status` would whine about this.
2. When using an en-masse `git add` that updates-or-adds *many* files, skip this one if it's not already there.

This file should perhaps be named `.git-do-not-complain-about-these-files-and-do-not-auto-add-them-with-en-masse-add-operations`, or something like that; but that name is ridiculous, so `.gitignore` it is, despite the semantic mismatch.

#### Why this makes it hard to do what you want

You have two commits, which we might want to call `A` and `B`, with two branch names identifying those two commits.  You used names `A` and `B` for branch names here but I'll rename them to `branch-A` and `branch-B`, and draw the commits like this:

```
  B   <-- branch-B
 /
A   <-- branch-A
```

Commit `A` contains one file named `A_file`.  Commit `B` contains two files, named `A_file` and `B_file`.

Checking out commit `A`, no matter how you do it—by hash ID, using `branch-A`, using `branch-B~1`, or whatever—results in a copy of `A_file` being in Git's index, and no copy of `B_file` being in Git's index.  If `B_file` *was* in Git's index, Git will remove that *and* remove the work-tree copy too.

Checking out commit `B`, however you do that—it's only findable by the name `branch-B` or its raw hash ID right now—results in a copy of `A_file` being in Git's index, and a copy of `B_file` being in Git's index.  This populates your work-tree with these files as well.

It doesn't matter what is in any ignore file, whether that is `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude` or anywhere else: these are the files that are in the *commit* snapshots, and therefore they must be copied to Git's index, whenever you switch to these commits.  That way, if you make a new commit on `branch-A`, it will have the correct set of files:

```
git checkout branch-A   # updates index to hold A_file and lack B_file
# do whatever work you do here
git commit              # makes new commit C from whatever is in Git's index
```

To send a new commit to some other Git, you must first make a new commit.  Then you can use `git push` to send that commit—with whatever snapshot it contains—to that other Git, and ask that other Git to update *its* branch name appropriately.

#### So what *should* you do?

There's no real right answer to this question, unfortunately.

The usual standard trick is to keep configuration information out of the Git repository entirely.  That's often a great idea because the *repository* might be widely available, and you don't want configuration items, including secret or at least intentionally-unpublished keys, in widely-available data.  But it's often nice to keep a repository with configuration data, for the same reason that we keep source code in repositories.

One workable hybrid is to keep the configuration in a *separate repository*.  This separate repository can be completely disconnected from the source repository, or you can use submodules (or raw gitlinks) to tie particular items together.  This does tend to call for the configuration file to be located outside the work-tree of the project, and that's usually a good idea.

Another option is to keep, in the project, a *sample* or *default* configuration.  The default configuration can be pretty useful: now a practical, useful configuration is very small, containing only those settings that aren't the defaults.  Should the project change and acquire more and/or different defaults, the running configuration might not need any changes at all.  This can work well whether or not you put the deployed configuration into another (separate) repository.

Comment: Thank you for explaining what I couldn’t.