# How to ignore files while working through git branches

Tags: git, github, local, ignore

I have a configuration file with the local config for my machine that I never want to change in my GIT Project, and `master` has its own version.

I want to be able to switch branches and leave that file changed (with my local configurations) forever, I thought that just leaving it without stashing will do the trick but when checking out to another branch (`master`) this message appeared:

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
> by merge:
> my.file Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge. Aborting

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15553660/1180993) that is very similar to what I'm looking for but I don't want to affect the master branch nor any of my teammates, I just want my local to stay that way.

**Is there a way to do this in git?**

Comment: Committing *actual* configuration files in Git is always a mistake (not your mistake, you inherited it, but now you have to live with it). You'll need to commit *your* version of this. Just makes *your own branch name*. Don't be afraid of branching and committing!

Comment: Once you've committed the file somewhere, you can take away all your changes and go back to someone else's version of the config file, as you do collaborative work. Then: grab *your* version of the file whenever you need it (using `git restore` in modern Git). Grab *their* version of the file whenever you need it (again, using `git restore`). You have *your* version saved away on *your branch*. Just make sure you use "their" version whenever you make commits you intend to give back.

Comment: Eventually, try to get everyone to fix this mistake: the *repository* should contain not the *actual configuration* but rather a *sample configuration*. If the config file would be named `foo.conf`, you'd never commit a `foo.conf`, only a `foo.conf.sample`, *ever*. So you can make an updated version of the software in which the config file's name has changed, and there *is no committed config file*, only a *sample*.

Comment: Users migrate to the new version of the software by checking it out as usual, then renaming or copying their *real* config file in place. It's carefully never *committed*, so nobody's config is ever in the *repository*. Only the sample is in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new file with a new name, github will try to merge only the files he know on his branch, but if there are a new file always will be your new file, i think you will need to change some configurations to work with your new file.

now if you change branch per branch your new file wont have any issues with git as long as you dont `add` it in some branch